# How can I get different SHA checksums for 'identical' iso files?

Tags: iso-image, checksum, crc

I have two ISO files, I call it

```
Windows 10 ISO #1.iso
Windows 10 ISO #2.iso
```

The checksums calculated with different tools show two different values  for this two *.iso files.
The two textfiles show the different checksums for #1 and #2 (calculated with [Nirsofts HashMyFiles.exe](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html)) 
The two dialog boxes from [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) confirm the different checksums for #1 and #2:
[image]

How can it be that a tool like [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) doesn't find any difference in the included files and directories and shows everything in "green" as identical?
[image]

How can it be that the checksums for the two *.ISO files #1 and #2 mounted with Windows 10 file explorer show the IDENTICAL SHA values?
[image]

In this case: Would you say the ISO are identical or not?

Comment: If check sums are not equal then by definition the files are **guaranteed to not be the same**. If check sums are equal then there is a high chance that the files are the same, but not 100% guarantee. Now for if the files are "close enough" to function, that is an entirely different question

Comment: Windows Explorer only shows file contents of the image. It does not show boot “sectors” or anything the like.

Comment: "Would you say the ISO are identical or not?" - [You should be comparing the hash provided by Microsoft generated by the same tool Microsoft used to calculate the hash they provided](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil).  It is not possible to make a determination using the information you provided.

Comment: Also, according to MSDN, `2F8910CE2CFAF61F094DFD49FE87AC004A6200AF` is the “real” file.

Comment: @DanielB - [It is my understanding that Microsoft stopped publishing the checksums for Windows 10 ISOs.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/does-microsoft-publish-the-checksums-of-the/16bcbe32-9f85-4e6e-baa7-83763292aaff)

Comment: They are not publicly available, that’s correct. However, because I have an active MSDN subscription, I can still view them.

Answer (score 2):

> How can it be that a tool like KDiff3 doesn't find any difference in the included files and directories and shows everything in "green" as identical?

The application is only looking at the contents of the image.  You are not comparing the boot sector of the image.

> Would you say the ISO are identical or not?

It is not possible to make this determination.  You should be comparing the checksum calculated by [certutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) and compare it to the checksum provided by Microsoft.  If you used the Media Creation Tool to download the ISO you are comparing, the checksum will be different, this is intentional behavior by Microsoft.